# VMware 4 ESXi on 64Bit CPU does it run 64Bit Guests?

Tags: vmware, x86-64, esxi, amd-processor

I have a PC with AMD FX CPU (Do not remember if it was FX51 or FX60)

it is 64Bit does it means that I can run 64Bit Guests? even if it does not have the Visualization extensions in the CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a question for Server Fault, but I don't have enough rep to vote for a move.

Assuming you can even install ESXi 4 on that CPU, it will be able to run a 64bit guest.